# Jquery ui repeat combined effect x times

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-effects

I have two effects combined with `.dequeue()`.
How can Make this effec repeat x-times ? 4 times,5times etc instead of just one run.

**[JSFIDDLE:](http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/US9z7/)**
**JS**:

```
$('somediv').effect( "highlight", 1000 ).dequeue().effect( "bounce", 1000 );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#test').click(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        setTimeout(bounce,i * 1500);
    }
});

function bounce(){
    $('#test').effect("highlight", 1000).dequeue().effect("bounce", 1000);
}
```

see a working example here http://jsfiddle.net/zqK47/